# Split div with LI into 4 columns with max of 10 per row

Tags: html, css

How can I split this div into 4 columns of equal width with a max of 10 per row?

I tried the following and several variations:

```
  <div class="column_split">
    <h2>Course Name</h2></br>
    <ul>
      {% for course in courses%}
          <li>{{ course}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

with the following bootstrap .css:

```
.column_split {
  column-count:4;
  row-count:10;
  column-gap: 30px;
}
```

Essentially i'm trying this:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-rule-color

With my LI from the for loop.  However, using the code in the tutorial doesn't seem to work.

Below is the html code:

```
<style>
  .column_split {
      -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
      column-count: 4;
      row-count: 10;
      -webkit-column-gap: 25px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -moz-column-gap: 25px; /* Firefox */
      column-gap: 25px;
      -webkit-column-rule-style: solid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -moz-column-rule-style: solid; /* Firefox */
      column-rule-style: solid;

      -webkit-column-rule-color: lightblue; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -moz-column-rule-color: lightblue; /* Firefox */
      column-rule-color: lightblue;
  }
  </style>
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Available Courses</h2></br>
        <div class ="column_split"
        <ul>

          {% for course in courses%}
              <li>{{ course  }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: There is no `row-count` property. The breaking point is determined by the column value and the *height* of the items. I suspect you will need JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to incorporate some JavaScript into your HTML code. I'm not sure if the "loop" you're using in the code works only for you, but it doesn't work for me unfortunately. Here's an example:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var array = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5"]
var x="<ul>", i, y = array.length;
for(i=1; i<=y; i++) {
x +=  "<li>" + array[I] + "</li>";
}
}
document.getElementByClass("column_split").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: This isn't what I wanted.  I have a single for loop that populates my LI. I want that LI split into 4 columns.  I included the example above.

Comment: So you're saying that you want to split the text in the LI into 4 columns?

Comment: With a max of 10 per row.

Comment: Hmm... Is it possible for you to show all the code you got? It might make it easier for everyone to help you out.

Comment: That was it Aidan, thank you.  I didn't realize I could use javascript for something like this.

Comment: You're welcome. I've had experience with HTML and JavaScript for quite a while now, so... Yeah. ^_^

Comment: Would you happen to have any recommendations on books to learn javascript?

Comment: Not books, no. But W3Schools has a great tutorial on JS - that's where I learned how to use it, after all. :)